# Git: Never Commit Changed Files (But still keep original revisioned.)

Tags: git, perforce

What is a good *git* practice to denote that a changed file should never be committed?

For example, for a WordPress theme development project, I am tracking the original WordPress files in *git*; and the *wp-config.php* config file, which contains local info that only pertains to the current system, needs to be changed but I don't want to commit it to *git*.

In Perforce, I used to save this type of event as a *[numbered changelist](http://www.perforce.com/perforce/doc.current/manuals/p4guide/04_files.html)* and never check it in. I was wondering whether a similar trick is available with *git*.

Comment: I believe you're looking for "gitignore"

Answer (score 36, accepted):

If you still want to keep `wp-config.php` versioned, but ignore any local change to it:

```
git update-index --assume-unchanged wp-config.php
```

This is different that a .gitignore, which would only work if you *remove* first `wp-config.php` from the index:

```
git rm --cache `wp-config.php`
echo wp-config.php >> .gitignore
```

Comment: Thank you! For others, this might help too: http://gitready.com/intermediate/2009/02/18/temporarily-ignoring-files.html

Answer (score -2):

You can use .gitignore file to solve this problem.

Comment: More information on how to use *.gitignore* would make this answer better.

Comment: for example, if you would not push files with suffix ".php"

Comment: you can create a .gitignore file in the directory and add a line like "*.php".

Comment: thank you for following up with comments, these certainly enhance your answer. Stack Overflow has a somewhat unique feature that allows you to Edit questions and answers. Editing your answer and incorporating these comments would be a great fix! Welcome to the community we are happy to have new members!